# What are the main must-know features of Haskell?

Tags: programming-languages, haskell, functional-programming

The question is about finding out which are the best features that everyone who is learning Haskell should pay attention to.

Comment: There's really only two interesting concepts in Haskell: purity and typing. All the rest are either prerequisites or consequences of those two.

Answer (score 3):

The biggest thing to keep in mind is laziness. Nothing is evaluated until it's forced to be. For example, Haskell doesn't have a ternary operator like you see in C-ish languages, but you can write your own just as a simple function.

```
infixl 1 ?

(?) :: Bool -> a -> a -> a
(?) True = const
(?) False = const id

main = 1 == 2 ? putStrLn "Oh no, the world is ending!" $ putStrLn "OK, math still works"
-- Only prints "OK, math still works"
```